# Not all code paths return a value error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to load my charts from the `Page_Load` event but getting this error "not all code paths return a value" and i am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Can someone help.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal2.Text = CreateChart_2();
}    

public string CreateChart_2()
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    // Initialize the string which would contain the chart data in XML format
    StringBuilder xmlStr = new StringBuilder();

    // Provide the relevant customization attributes to the chart
    xmlStr.Append("<chart decimalPrecision='0' showShadow='1' showborder='1' caption='Number of Lots Assigned (YTD)' subcaption='" + result1 + "'   name='MyXScaleAnim' type='ANIMATION' duration='1' start='0' param='_xscale' showNames='1' labelDisplay='Rotate'  useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1' formatNumberScale='0'>");        
    {
        // Establish the connection with the database
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT count (ID)as TotalCount, cat_name FROM MyTable group by cat_name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        // Begin iterating through the result set
        //SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Construct the chart data in XML format
            xmlStr.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["cat_name"].ToString(), reader["TotalCount"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("DrillDown1.aspx?AppName=" + reader["cat_name"].ToString()));
        }

        // End the XML string
        xmlStr.Append("</chart>");

        // Close the result set Reader object and the Connection object
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

        // Set the rendering mode to JavaScript, from the default Flash.
        FusionCharts.SetRenderer("javascript");

        // Call the RenderChart method, pass the correct parameters, and write the return value to the Literal tag
        Literal2.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart(
            "FusionChartsXT/Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
            "", // Page which returns chart data. Leave blank when using Data String.
            xmlStr.ToString(), // String containing the chart data. Leave blank when using Data URL.
            "annual_revenue",   // Unique chart ID
            "640", "340",       // Width & Height of chart
            false,              // Disable Debug Mode
            true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method should return a `string`, but I don't seem to find a `return` statement anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a return to your method:

**Option 1 - with return**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal2.Text = CreateChart_2();
}


public string CreateChart_2()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    // Initialize the string which would contain the chart data in XML format
    StringBuilder xmlStr = new StringBuilder();

    // Provide the relevant customization attributes to the chart
    xmlStr.Append("<chart decimalPrecision='0' showShadow='1' showborder='1' caption='Number of Lots Assigned (YTD)' subcaption='" + result1 + "'   name='MyXScaleAnim' type='ANIMATION' duration='1' start='0' param='_xscale' showNames='1' labelDisplay='Rotate'  useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1' formatNumberScale='0'>");


    {
        // Establish the connection with the database
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT count (ID)as TotalCount, cat_name FROM MyTable group by cat_name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        // Begin iterating through the result set
        //SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Construct the chart data in XML format
            xmlStr.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["cat_name"].ToString(), reader["TotalCount"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("DrillDown1.aspx?AppName=" + reader["cat_name"].ToString()));
        }

        // End the XML string
        xmlStr.Append("</chart>");

        // Close the result set Reader object and the Connection object
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

        // Set the rendering mode to JavaScript, from the default Flash.
        FusionCharts.SetRenderer("javascript");

        // Call the RenderChart method, pass the correct parameters, and write the return value to the Literal tag
        Literal2.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart(
            "FusionChartsXT/Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
            "", // Page which returns chart data. Leave blank when using Data String.
            xmlStr.ToString(), // String containing the chart data. Leave blank when using Data URL.
            "annual_revenue",   // Unique chart ID
            "640", "340",       // Width & Height of chart
            false,              // Disable Debug Mode
            true);

    }
    return xmlStr.ToString();

}
```

**Option 2 - without return**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateChart_2();
}


public void CreateChart_2()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    // Initialize the string which would contain the chart data in XML format
    StringBuilder xmlStr = new StringBuilder();

    // Provide the relevant customization attributes to the chart
    xmlStr.Append("<chart decimalPrecision='0' showShadow='1' showborder='1' caption='Number of Lots Assigned (YTD)' subcaption='" + result1 + "'   name='MyXScaleAnim' type='ANIMATION' duration='1' start='0' param='_xscale' showNames='1' labelDisplay='Rotate'  useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1' formatNumberScale='0'>");


    {
        // Establish the connection with the database
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT count (ID)as TotalCount, cat_name FROM MyTable group by cat_name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        // Begin iterating through the result set
        //SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Construct the chart data in XML format
            xmlStr.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["cat_name"].ToString(), reader["TotalCount"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("DrillDown1.aspx?AppName=" + reader["cat_name"].ToString()));
        }

        // End the XML string
        xmlStr.Append("</chart>");

        // Close the result set Reader object and the Connection object
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

        // Set the rendering mode to JavaScript, from the default Flash.
        FusionCharts.SetRenderer("javascript");

        // Call the RenderChart method, pass the correct parameters, and write the return value to the Literal tag
        Literal2.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart(
            "FusionChartsXT/Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
            "", // Page which returns chart data. Leave blank when using Data String.
            xmlStr.ToString(), // String containing the chart data. Leave blank when using Data URL.
            "annual_revenue",   // Unique chart ID
            "640", "340",       // Width & Height of chart
            false,              // Disable Debug Mode
            true);

    }


}
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to return anything from `CreateChart_2()` then you can change the signature to:

```
public void CreateChart_2()
```

and therefore you are not required to return.

Comment: i have changed to public void but getting different error now like this: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'"  thanks.

Comment: change `Literal2.Text = CreateChart_2();` to just `CreateChart_2();` in your `Page_Load()`

Answer (score 6):

Your method signature says that it should return a `string`.. yet you don't have a `return` statement anywhere.

Your callsite is:

```
Literal2.Text = CreateChart_2();
```

But you're doing this in your function:

```
Literal2.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart(
            "FusionChartsXT/Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
            "", // Page which returns chart data. Leave blank when using Data String.
            xmlStr.ToString(), // String containing the chart data. Leave blank when using Data URL.
            "annual_revenue",   // Unique chart ID
            "640", "340",       // Width & Height of chart
            false,              // Disable Debug Mode
            true);
```

You have two options.

1. Change the return type of your function to `void`. This is preferable because you're already setting the `Literal`'s text property within the method.
2. Change that last part of your function to `return FusionCharts.RenderChart(....`.

Comment: @downvoter: I did update my answer after my original 1 liner :)

Comment: Your 1 liner was incorrect because it doesn't actually return a string if there is no `return` so I removed my upvote, sorry

Comment: @Simon I know the feeling , there's always one! :/

Comment: Anyway I only meant to remove the upvote, accidentally downvoted, but I just fixed that

Comment: @Tim I'm unsure what you mean. The method signature clearly states that it is meant to return a `string`.. and yet it doesn't.. ?

Comment: It doesn't, but your first sentence says that it does "Your method returns a string"

Comment: @Tim I think you've just misunderstood my way of talking.. I have updated to make it more clear.

Comment: +1 You should probably mention that your first option should be preferred since he is already setting the `Literal`-control's Text in the method. So returning the string to assign it again to the control would be pointless. The method-name also suggests void.